# On automorphisms group of direct product of two groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be two finite groups. We know if $\alpha\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\beta\in \mathrm{Aut}(H)$, then $\alpha\times\beta\in \mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$. Hence, $| \mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)|\geq| \mathrm{Aut}(G)\times  \mathrm{Aut}(H)|$. Also we know if $(|G|,| H|)=1$, then  $| \mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)|=| \mathrm{Aut}(G)\times  \mathrm{Aut}(H)|$.

Now, can we say that  if $(| G|,| H|)\neq1$, then  $| \mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)|>| \mathrm{Aut}(G)\times  \mathrm{Aut}(H)|$?