# Let $H,K$ be normal subgroups of group $G$, if $\gcd\left(|H|,|K|\right)=1$ then $\text{Aut}(H\times K)=\text{Aut}(H)\times \text{Aut}(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you help me with the following problem?

Let $H,K$ be normal subgroups of group $G$, if $\gcd\left(|H|,|K|\right)=1$ then $\text{Aut}(H \times K)=\text{Aut}(H)\times \text{Aut}(K)$.

Is it true that $\text{Aut}(H)\times\text{Aut}(K)$ is contained in $\text{Aut}(H \times K)$ regardless of coprimeness? Why?

How to use coprimeness to show the other containing?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420884/if-g-h-1-does-it-follow-that-operatornameautg-times-h-neq-o).

Comment: related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420884/if-g-h-1-does-it-follow-that-operatornameautg-times-h-neq-o

Comment: Use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, yes, we can identify $\mathrm{Aut}(H)\times\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ with a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(H\times K)$.

This is because any $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)$, $g\in\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ induce automorphisms $f',g'\in\mathrm{Aut}(H\times K)$ by $f'(h,k)=(f(h),k)$ and $g'(h,k)=(h,g(k))$. Clearly $f'$ and $g'$ always commute, so $\mathrm{Aut}(H)\times\mathrm{Aut}(K)\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(H\times K)$ via $(f,g)\mapsto f'g'$.

For the second part, the opposite inclusion, consider $\rho\in\mathrm{Aut}(H\times K)$. For $h\in H$, $\rho(h)$ must have the same order as $H$. Since $H$ and $K$ have coprime order, the only elements with the same order as $h$ must be in $H$, so $\rho(H)=H$. In particular $\rho$ restricts to an automorphism $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. Similarly, $\rho$ restricts to some $g\in\mathrm{Aut}(K)$. Noticing then that $\rho=f'g'$, we obtain $\rho\in\mathrm{Aut}(H)\times\mathrm{Aut}(K)$.

Comment: Doesn't this only prove that these automorphism groups are equal as sets? Why does this prove that they are isomorphic as groups?

Comment: the first part $(f,g)\mapsto f'g'$ defines an injective homomorphism, the second part shows that the homomorphism is surjective