# Is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3)$ isomorphic with $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)\times \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Is  $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3)$ isomorphic with $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)\times \operatorname{Aut}\left(\mathbb{Z}_3\right)$?

From the lecture I know that $\operatorname{Aut}\left(G\times H\right)\simeq \operatorname{Aut}\left(G\right)\times \operatorname{Aut}\left(H\right)$ if gcd$(G,H)=1$ but I don't know what I can use when $G=H$ so $\gcd(G,H)\neq1$.

Can I have any tips?

Comment: No; for example, there's an automorphism that swaps the two factors. $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3)$ is $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What is $\mathbb F_3$?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_3$ is the finite field of order $3$; it's another term for $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which emphasizes that it's being used as a ring, not just as an abelian group.

Comment: Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420884/if-g-h-1-does-it-follow-that-operatornameautg-times-h-neq-o?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Note that we have $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ so we can safely write
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3}) \times \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$
However, if we consider an automorphism $\sigma$ in $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3})$ with $\sigma(1,0) = (0,2)$ and $\sigma(0,1) = (1,0)$, we have $o(\sigma) = 4$ but there is no element of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not obvious to me: how to prove that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: An automorphism is determined by where it sends the generators to. $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is cyclic so it can be generated by only one element, say $1$. Then, we must map $1$ to either $1$ or $2$ (note that $2$ is also a generator so sending $1$ to $2$ also gives us an automorphism). So, $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3)| = 2$.

Answer (score 3):

For every integer $n \geq 2$, the *homomorphisms* of $\mathbf Z/(n) \times \mathbf Z/(n)$ to itself are the linear maps given by $2 \times 2$ mod $n$ matrices $A = (\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})$, which act on $\mathbf Z/(n) \times \mathbf Z/(n)$ by $A\binom{x}{y} = \binom{ax+cy}{bx+dy}$.  This homomorphism is invertible if and only if the matrix is invertible, which means $\det A$ is invertible mod $n$. Such $A$ form the group ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbf Z/(n))$ of invertible $2 \times 2$ mod $n$ matrices. So ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf Z/(n) \times \mathbf Z/(n)) = {\rm GL}_2(\mathbf Z/(n))$.

By similar reasoning, for all $d \geq 1$ we have ${\rm Aut}(({\mathbf Z}/(n))^d) = {\rm GL}_d(\mathbf Z/(n))$, where $d \times d$ mod $n$ matrices act on vectors in $(\mathbf Z/(n))^d$ in the natural way.

A very simple reason ${\rm Aut}(G \times G)$ is not pairs of automorphisms of $G$, when $G$ is a nontrivial group, is that there is always the swap automorphism $f(g,g') = (g',g)$.